# Improve String.Insert in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I need to mark up a string with identifiers indicating the start and end of a substring that has passed a test.

Assume I had the string "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" and I wanted to markup the string with a tag for every word starting with the characters 'b' and 'o'. The final string would look like "The quick `<tag>brown</tag>` fox jumps `<tag>over</tag>` the lazy dog".

Using a combination of regular expressions and LINQ I have the correct logic to accomplish what I want but my performance is not what I want it to be because I am using String.Insert to insert the tags. Our strings can be very long (>200k) and the number of substrings to tag can be close to a hundred. Below is the code I am using to insert the tags. Given I know the start and length of each substring how can I update the string 'input' faster?

```
.ForEach<Match>(m => {
  input = input.Insert(m.Index + m.Length, "</tag>");
  input = input.Insert(m.Index, "<tag>");
});
```

Comment: Can you use a solution based on regular expressions?

Comment: I think I need to explain myself more clear. I am using RegEx but I cannot use Replace because I do not want to perform the Replace on all matches only some of them. So I call Where, with my test condition, against the MatchCollection output by my RegEx call and pipe the resulting output collection to the Foreach described above.

Comment: Like SLaks says below, there's an overload of `RegEx.Replace` that lets you pass in a function that is called for every match. Inside that function, you can decide on a case-by-case basis what to do about each match.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use a `StringBuilder`.

For optimal performance, set the `StringBuilder`'s capacity before doing anything, then append chunks of the original string between tags.

Alternatively, move your logic to a `MatchEvaluator` lambda expression and call `RegeEx.Replace`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Using MatchEvaluator is the way to go. It is a lot cleaner than what I was doing and seems faster.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

#### Regex

```
Regex.Replace("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", @"(^|\s)([bo]\w*)", "$1<tag>$2</tag>");
```

#### Results

```
The quick <tag>brown</tag> fox jumps <tag>over</tag> the lazy dog
```

Regular expressions should provide with a fairly quick replacement. Whether or not this method is the best depends on the length of the string and how much work is involved to actually match one of your "words."

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added a comment to the original post. I think it clarifies why I cannot use Regex.Replace.

Comment: Could your "where" clause be moved into the regex? (Can you post the "where" part?)

Comment: .Where(a => ECAUtil.stemming.LuceneQueryStemmer.StemQuery(a.Value).Equals(stemmedkeyword)). The regex is a mix of stemmed/unstemmed words/phrases. The test above rejects all matched phrases whose stem is not equal to the stemmed word/phrase.

Answer (score 1):

String manipulation is notoriously slow.  Use a [System.Text.StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) instead.

It also has an [Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.insert.aspx) method.

Also, MSDN has a nice article on improving [Improving String Handling Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302329.aspx)  that compares the StringBuilder to normal String operations.  It's worth a read if you've never ran across this topic before.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RegEx` directly - it has a [`Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx) method which should allow you to insert the tags around your matches.

I can't vouch for the speed of this, however. You can [compile](http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Regular_Expression_Recipes%E2%80%94Compiling_Regular_Expressions) the `RegEx`, which should improve performance, but even with this you will need to test with your specific circumstances.